# COCO keypoints annotation wrong order from CVAT

Tags: annotations, keypoint, coco, cvat

I have annotated and downloaded COCO keypoint annotations from the CVAT software but the points are in the wrong order. Has anyone else encountered this issue? If so how did you get around it?

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue with CVAT itself and has been handled in more recent releases. If you still have issues with this, post an issue on their github.